# Show that a solution doesn't exist for this system of equations

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to show that there is not a solution for this system of equations: (the unknowns are $P_1$ and $P_2$)

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{P_1} = \left( {\mu  + 1} \right) + b{P_2} - \sqrt {\mu \left( {\mu  + 1 + bP_2} \right)} , \quad \quad \quad {P_2} > \frac{{\frac{\mu }{{{{\left( {1 - \theta } \right)}^2}}} - \left( {\mu  + 1} \right)}}{b}\\
{P_2} = 1 + b{P_1} - \frac{{\theta \mu }}{{1 - \theta }},\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  \,{P_1} < \frac{{\frac{\mu }{{{{\left( {1 - \theta } \right)}^2}}} - \left( {\mu  + 1} \right)}}{b}
\end{array} \right.$

Also, we know that: $0 < b,\mu ,\theta  < 1$, and $P_1, P_2 > 0$ , and finally $\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{P_1} - b{P_2} \le 1\\
{P_2} - b{P_1} \le 1
\end{array} \right.$.

In fact, the values of $P_1$ and $P_2$ are not important to me. I want to show that the $P_1$ and $P_2$ that solve the above system do not fit in the conditions I mentioned. Is there a way that anyone can guess to prove this? I tried MATLAB or WolframAlpha; the answer I get from MATLAB is so weird mathematically (lots of lines of parameters) that you cannot check a condition with it, and WolframAlpha gave me the runtime error!

Comment: What are the unknowns?

Comment: Only $P_1$ and $P_2$

Comment: Is $P$ another constant in the 1st equation, or is it a typo and you meant $P_1$ or $P_2$?

Comment: Oh, my bad! Thanks for mentioning it! I fixed it.

Comment: The second equation gives you $P_2$ as a function of $P_1$. Plug that into the first equation. Now your transformed first equation only has 1 variable ($P_1$). After that, put the square root alone on one side of that equation, and take the square of both sides. You end up with a quadratic equation in $P1$. Look at the discriminant to see if there are real solutions.

Comment: The problem is that when I want to derive the solution (in your case, to find $P_1$), the answer is sooo long that I cannot do any calculations with it). I was trying to find a way to prove that the conditions won't be met without finding the solution.